# React js firebase getting specific data

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have listed movies in Movies list component and the movie list component is rendered in the App component. When I click on each movie it takes me to specific url: `http://localhost:3000/details/Ironman`.

How can I get the movie details (`Name`, `year`, `synopsis`, `image`, etc) of that movie from Firebase?

Comment: Have you tried going through `Firebase`'s documentation?

Comment: yes i just wanna know how to get the detils of each movie. when i click the image of the movie..

Comment: It is better if you post your code, and also post what undesired behaviors you are experiencing, otherwise, it is nearly impossible to figure out why your specific case is not working.

Comment: HI this is my code..      class MovieList extends Component{
   render(){
     const {movie} = this.props;
      return(
          <div className="col-md-3">
             <Link to={"/details/" + movie.name}>
                <img src={movie.image} alt={movie.name} className="thumbnail"/>
             </Link>
          </div>
      )
   }
}

Comment: and this is my movie details component     import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Details extends Component{

   render(){
      return(
          <div>
           {this.props.match.params.movie}
          </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Details;
i wanna show details of each in this page...